# How to enable website openning via 443 port of apache in CentOS7

Tags: apache-2.2, centos7

I have website working fine under `http` (CentOS 7) and would like to 
get it working under `https` and port **443**.

When I navigate to root of the domain under `https` I see the text

> It Works!

So it seems like `apache` is configuted to listen **443**?

Have I need to configure something else in order get working website via **443** port?

Thank you!

Comment: Listening on 443 and using SSL are 2 different things, you could configure Apache to use 443 for normal non-ssl http: traffic. When you use the https:// address does it give you the site or only when you say http: and use port 443?

Comment: Listening 443 on httpd.conf does not meant that it is secured. Do the same thing in ssl.conf, and check through https://

Comment: @NickYoung Well... When I use just `http + 443` like this `http : / / mydomain.com:443/web2project/` it says `400 Bad Request` and it says `Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.`

Comment: @vembutech Hi, well... I cannot see `ssl.conf` in the folder of `httpd.conf`. Is it ok?

Comment: usually it should be in  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ . Or do a search "locate ssl.conf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It Works!` means you didn't complete configuring your Apache just yet, take a look at following document: [SSL/TLS Strong Encryption: How-To - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to see your webpage when the URL is `https://example.com`, you don't need to worry about manually specifying port 443, because SSL/TLS is working automatically.

You can confirm this by using a number of tools. OpenSSL, for example:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

The output should be pretty explicit in whether or not SSL/TLS is enabled. Specifically, it'll returned the message `CONNECTED`, followed by a lot of SSL handshake info.

Also, you can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ if your site is available on the internet.